# Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens (search filter php mvc)

Tags: php, search, model-view-controller

Im trying to make a search filter for table products and im trying to have pagination and filter in the same sql query. Im using a MVC pattern.

This is the model:

```
    <?php

namespace Dao\test;

use Dao\Table;

class Productos extends Table
{
    public static function obtenerProductos($list, $search, $numPerPage)
    {
        $startFrom = (intval($list)-1)*$numPerPage;
        $sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE name LIKE '%:search%' LIMIT :startFrom,:numPerPage;";
        $parametros = array(
            "search" => $search,
            "startFrom" => $startFrom,
            "numPerPage" => $numPerPage
        );
        return self::obtenerRegistros($sqlStr, $parametros);
    }

    public static function obtenerNumeroProductos()
    {
        $sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM productos;";
        return self::obtenerRegistros($sqlStr, array());
    }
}

?>
```

This is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace Controllers\test;

use Controllers\PublicController;
use Views\Renderer;

class Productoss extends PublicController
{
    public function run() :void
    {
        \Utilities\Site::addLink("/public/css/test1.css");

        if(isset($_GET["search"])){
            $search = $_GET["search"];
        }else{
            $search="";
        }

        $numPerPage = 5;

        if(isset($_GET["list"])){
            $list=$_GET["list"];
        }
        else{
            $list=1;
        }

        $viewData = array(
            "totalProductos" => 0,
            "totalList" => "",
        );

        $viewData["producto"] = \Dao\test\Productos::obtenerProductos($list, $search, $numPerPage);
        $viewData["lista"] = \Dao\test\Productos::obtenerNumeroProductos();

        foreach ($viewData["lista"] as $producto) {
            $viewData["totalProductos"] = $viewData["totalProductos"] + 1; 
        }

        $viewData["totalList"] = ceil($viewData["totalProductos"]/$numPerPage);

        for ($i=1; $i <= $viewData["totalList"]; $i++) {
            $viewData["nList"]["number"] = $i;
            $viewData["nPages"][] = $viewData["nList"];
        }

        if($list<$viewData["totalList"]){
            $viewData["next"] = true;
            $viewData["nextBtn"] = $list+1;
        }
        
        if ($list>1) {
            $viewData["previous"] = true;
            $viewData["prevBtn"] = $list - 1;
        }

        Renderer::render("test/Productoss", $viewData);
    }
}

?>
```

I get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
> number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPmvc\SimplePHPMvcOPP\src\Dao\Table.php:70 Stack
> trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPmvc\SimplePHPMvcOPP\src\Dao\Table.php(70):
> PDOStatement->execute() #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPmvc\SimplePHPMvcOPP\src\Dao\test\Productos.php(18):
> Dao\Table::obtenerRegistros('SELECT * FROM p...', Array) #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPmvc\SimplePHPMvcOPP\src\Controllers\test\Productoss.php(34):
> Dao\test\Productos::obtenerProductos(1, 'a', 5) #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPmvc\SimplePHPMvcOPP\index.php(27):
> Controllers\test\Productoss->run() #4 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPmvc\SimplePHPMvcOPP\src\Dao\Table.php on line 70

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer, what i did was this:

```
public static function obtenerLaboratorios($list, $search, $numPerPage)
    {
        $startFrom = (intval($list)-1)*$numPerPage;
        if(!empty($search)){
            $sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM laboratorio WHERE `laboratorioNombre` LIKE :search LIMIT :startFrom,:numPerPage;";
            $parametros = array(
                "search" => "%$search%",
                "startFrom" => $startFrom,
                "numPerPage" => $numPerPage
            );
        }else{
            $sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM laboratorio LIMIT :startFrom,:numPerPage;";
            $parametros = array(
                "startFrom" => $startFrom,
                "numPerPage" => $numPerPage
            );
        }
        return self::obtenerRegistros($sqlStr, $parametros);
    }
```

This way the mvc doesn't take the error for the '' symbols, that was what cause me problems. Takes the value of the variable `$search` and just puts the "%" in the start/end of the variable.